# Python loop (for or while) to add keep adding values from a list as long as they don't exceed a given condition

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

please help. I am trying to write a loop that will take values from a list `mylist = [3,4,7,10,6,8]` and keep adding them as long as the sum does not exceed 24.

```
myvar = 0
mylist = [3,4,7,10,6,8]

while myvar <= 24:
 print(myvar)
 for i in mylist:
  myvar+=i
  print(myvar)enter code here
```

what am I doing wrong here?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what you are looking for:

```
mylist = [3,4,7,10,6,8]
sum = 0

for var in mylist:
    if sum + var > 24:
        break
    sum += var

print(sum)
```

Also, consider using the module numpy for numerical calculations.

Comment: Thank you,  that worked, I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: One hint: you shouldn't call your variable `sum` because you overwrite the builtin [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function. Use a name like `total` instead.

Comment: Numpy for such beginner problems seems an overkill. Also, `sum` is a builtin function. Please do not use it as a variable name.

Comment: @JackTheCrab I thought about adding a a similar remark about the usage of `numpy` too.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're running into is that the check for `myvar <= 24` only happens when the code hits that line. In your case, it checks it once the first time through, sees that it's `0`, then proceeds to hit `for i in mylist`, at which point, it iterates through the list, doing `myvar+=i` for every item. Since we didn't get back to the `myvar <= 24` check until after all of the items in `mylist` were added, it doesn't stop execution until all the values of `mylist` were added to `myvar` once and the code loops back to your `myvar <= 24` test. What you may want to try instead is something more along the lines of

```
myvar = 0
mylist = [3,4,7,10,6,8]

for i in mylist:
  if myvar + i <= 24:
      myvar += i
  else:
      break
```

This has two benefits: One, that it doesn't keep adding things after hitting 24, and also that it checks that adding the new value wouldn't exceed 24.

There are a number of ways you can accomplish what you're after, and this is only one. There are probably prettier ways, but I think this is the easiest to understand for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop adds them all up already, so you are looping too much! There are different solutions to this:

```
myvar = 0
mylist = [3,4,7,10,6,8]

for i in mylist:
  myvar+=i
  if myvar > 24:
    myvar-=i
    break
print(myvar)
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to take values from your list and to add them in a variable as long as they do not exceed 24.

```
myvar = 0
mylist = [3,4,7,10,6,8]

print(myvar)
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if myvar + mylist[i] <= 24:
        myvar += mylist[i]
        print(myvar)
    else:
        break
```

and the result is:
the print function will show 0 then 3  7  14  24
**the final value of myval** is 24

Answer (score 1):

add values of your list to the variable as long as it doesn't exceed 24, if you want to use a while loop you can try this:

```
myvar = 0
mylist = [3,4,7,10,6,8]

print(myvar)
i = 0
while myvar <= 24:
    if myvar + mylist[i] <= 24:
        enter code heremyvar += mylist[i]
        print(myvar)
    else:
        break
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use only one loop. In this way, the inner loop adds the whole list every time, because the condition `<=24` is only checked in the outer loop.

You could use a for loop, and check internally the result.

```
myvar = 0
mylist = [3,4,7,10,6,8]

for i in mylist:
    if myvar <= 24:
        myvar += i
    else:
        break
```

The break condition is optional but stops the loop once the total sum is reached. If the sum of the values in the list is less than 24, this will return the sum of the list instead.

Note: There is no check that the items in the list are all numbers.